# Get the centers of grid() in r

Tags: r, plot

I have plotted some points using plot() in R and I have used grid() function to grid the whole area.

```
plot(rb22,xlim=c(4027200,4030200),ylim=c(697500,700100)) 
grid()
```

I just need to get the coordinates of the centers of these grids. Can anyone please help me to get the centers of each grid cell, please? Thanks!

The plot looks like 
[image: this].

Comment: I need to get the centers of each grid cell. but thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not provide your data so I cannot do this on your plot, but I can demonstrate on built-in data. The function `axTicks` will give you the coordinates of the grid marks themselves. Of course,  the centers are half-way between the successive grid marks.

```
## Illustrative graph
plot(iris[,3:4], pch=20, col=rainbow(3)[iris$Species], ylim=c(0,2.5))
grid()

## Now get the x & y for the centers
Tx = axTicks(1)
Ty = axTicks(2)
Midx = (Tx[-1] + head(Tx, -1)) /2
Midy = (Ty[-1] + head(Ty, -1)) /2
```

Midx has all the x-coordinates of centers. Midy has all of the y-coordinates. You can go through all combinations to do something with them.  I illustrate by plotting a box at the grid centers

```
Junk = sapply(Midx, 
    function(x) sapply(Midy, 
        function(y) points(x,y, pch=22, cex=0.7,bg="orange")))
```

[image: Grid Centers marked]